# Slow motion jump through Concrete wall

Tags: sound-design, foley

Need help on that sound. Its the Peak of an ad so it needs to be Perfect.

Its a long 10-20 sec Jump through a Concrete wall that bursts into piepes.

My First tought was timestretching Sand/ Stone foleys layerd with omnisphere Textures.

For the Hit i would Layer cracking Sounds over foley hits.

But it just dont get it right! Any Starter idea? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try any sort of hard solid debris. Ground slide, brick debris, rock debris, demolition sounds...

For the most time (actually always, when you don't know that you need to add a chorus or a granulizer or something), limit yourself to thinking only about pitch shifting and cutting processing-wise. Limit yourself to what a basic digital sound sampler does. If those don't seem viable or cannot produce anything that ticks, the sample or recording in hand is not what you're looking for, so move on.

Spend more time on recording or listening through samples than expecting a plug-in/a DSP process to make something work. This works almost every time in something that wouldn't have to be clearly "processed" (e.g. granulized), at some point you'll notice something that works and you'll very likely find it faster than by playing with plug-ins and the wrong samples.

Think backwards from the "expected goal", rather than forwards to a goal. Why your "goal" should result in one way, but not the other? What practice and use of your time makes most sense for a given task? Found a recording that fits exactly? Then use it and move on.

Spend more time on listening to samples or recording them.

Comment: Yeah im too much of a dsp Freak. I try Demolition with debris thx!

Comment: Never tought of debris, i found some that cracks thx

Answer (score 1):

@0-5pirc is great advice

I would also suggest working in stems ie sets of tracks, so you can control the multiple tracks feeding each stem as a group eg

- FXA Impact
- FXB Debris
- FXC Movement
- FXD Tonal

each stem might have eg 8 or mre tracks feeding it, but it could make eg mixing/crossing between real elements and subjective/tonal elements easier to experiment with...

Also do try experimenting with related sounds eg ice cracks, pitched glass breaks etc.... The different frequency range may be helpful

Comment: Yeah i have a Mic next week, so i will Post my first atemps. Working in stems is a good idea especially with the tonal Stuff since i so Not know the Key of the backing track of the ad. I think i will try timestretched learher crunching in. Im very excited! :D